# iOS build/version numbering

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I've read through this page here and I have a quick question before I actually do anything...

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2420/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016603-CH1-TWO_NAMING_CONVENTIONS_FOR_VERSION_NUMBERS_AND_BUILD_NUMBERS

This says:

> "Important: For macOS apps, build numbers must monotonically increase even across different versions. In other words, for macOS apps you cannot use the same build numbers again in different release trains. iOS apps have no such restriction and you can re-use the same build numbers again in different release trains."

Say I've accidentally uploaded build number 25 on to version 3.0.

If I upload build number 23 to version 3.0.1, is that acceptable?

This is an iOS app.  I was hoping someone has some experience with this before I just go for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's acceptable for iOS (and not acceptable for MacOS).

And by the way, you have the option to validate the version before uploading it to the store - that would warn you about such errors.